# Reverse proxy as an alternative to QuotaGuard Static IP

Tags: heroku, reverse-proxy, static-ip-address

For cost reasons, my company would like to setup a reverse proxy as an alternative to QuotaGuard Static IP.

Our clients access our backend API (running on Heroku dyno) from their Android pads through their proxy which requires a static IP as a target resource (our API).

To quickly respond to this constraint, we setup QuotaGuard Static IP which is quite expensive.

Is replacing QuotaGuard Static IP by a reverse proxy we would manage ourselves a good alternative ?